# jQuery if position equals check

Tags: jquery

How can i check if position equals?

trying to reach something like this:

```
if($(element).css({ left: "468px"}) == 468)

else
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```
if($(element).position().left == 468)
```

The `.position()` method has 2 properties, top and left.  This gives you top and left relative to the parent element.  If you need the position relative to the document, use `.offset()`:

```
if($(element).offset().left == 468)
```

Answer (score 2):

`.css()` takes either [one or two params](http://api.jquery.com/css/).

```
if($(element).css('left') == '468px') {
  //  do stuff
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PeeHaa/mEP2V/